# Congrats to Handy Howie & Anarach for reaching the 3k point milestone!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

Just a note of congratulations to both @HandyHowie and @Anarach for recently reaching the 3,000 point milestone. Please take a moment to throw them some love!

Comment: Moved to tears.  Thanks.

Comment: @HandyHowie - You should be, darn it! :D Congrats bro ... small, but sure bits.

Comment: @HandyHowie  I'm getting a little misty myself.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - No comments from the peanut gallery! ;-)

Comment: Seriously, congratulations to both of you two.  I've read a lot of your responses over the last 12 months.  Look forward to running into you two in chat.

Comment: Wow, Thank you guys, Didnt expect this :-)

Comment: @Anarach  you should come to chat more  :-)   We never talked about stand up riding in India along with poor road conditions.  Congratulations!

Comment: @DucatiKiller Basically , The thing u folks call motocross over the pond, we do it everyday (commuting)

Comment: @Anarach  lmao - touche'.  You should you come here and start racing, there's good money in it and the chic's dig it.   :-)